# Null Pointer Exception print in needs a message error from sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm getting a NullPointerException: println needs a message Error when trying to start an activity. I can't see the error.

Here is my database concerning the error

```
public HashMap<String, String> getsaleInfo(String saleId) {
    HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM SUPERSALE where supersaleId='"+saleId+"'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            wordList.put("saleCust", cursor.getString(1));
            wordList.put("saleName", cursor.getString(2));
            wordList.put("saleTime", cursor.getString(4));
            wordList.put("saleTax", cursor.getString(5));
            wordList.put("saleNotes", cursor.getString(6));
               //wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }                   
return wordList;
}
```

And here is how I retrieve in the activity

```
        saleCust = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saleCust);
        saleNotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saleNotes);
        saleName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saleName);
        saleTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saleTime);
        saleTax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saleTax);

Intent objIntent = getIntent();
        String saleId = objIntent.getStringExtra("supersaleId");
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        HashMap<String, String> saleList = controller.getsaleInfo(saleId);
        Log.d("saleCust",saleList.get("saleCust"));
        Log.d("saleName",saleList.get("saleName"));
        Log.d("saleTime",saleList.get("saleTime"));
        Log.d("saleTax",saleList.get("saleTax"));
        Log.d("saleNotes",saleList.get("saleNotes"));

        if(saleList.size()!=0) {
            saleCust.setText(saleList.get("saleCust"));
            saleName.setText(saleList.get("saleName"));
            saleTime.setText(saleList.get("saleTime"));
            saleTax.setText(saleList.get("saleTax"));
            saleNotes.setText(saleList.get("saleNotes"));

        }}
```

The error is coming from line

```
Log.d("saleCust",saleList.get("saleCust"));
```

Comment: `saleList.get("saleCust")` may be null. check it

Comment: It's not..when I retrieve the same value on other activities it's shows up fine...The previous activity actually shows "saleCust" so I know it's in the database and the value is right. I'm lost

Comment: you can check with a simple if conditions before you display the same in log.

Comment: is supersaleId really a string?.. or is it intended to be integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your logcat next time and your UI activity in question.  Since you have textview from your layout, you could be using a Listview, ExpandedListView, etc.  If so, android view's require that there is a column _id in your table and is retrieved in your query so that the view can keep in sync with the data adapter's data from your database cursor via the _id column.

Hope this helps.